# Profile for users and Page for companies?

Tags: website-design, navigation, structure

My question is mostly about the name of it.
A company to view their personal account options visiting `domain.com/page`

On the other hand, users can see their personal account options with `domain.com/profile`.
On both cases, their public profile/page can be accessed by `domain.com/the-username`.
The question is because technically they can not both go to the same path e.g. `domain.com/profile` I thought of having the name **page for companies** and **profile for users**.

How do you find this?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear to me so maybe my answer does not make sense.

If I understand correctly there are 3 pages of which you are looking for name:

1. a users' personal account page
2. a company's account page
3. a public profile page

How about naming them:

1. User Account (domain.com/useraccount)
2. Company Account (domain.com/companyaccount)
3. Public Profile (domain.com/the-username)

In any case, a page named "page" is very weird. It's like a book named "Book", or a child name "Child".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the site that's doing this started doing it recently, I think this is a case of copying Facebook.

On Facebook, companies, interests ect have "Pages", this is in part because products and services used to act just like normal people, they were 'friends' and they had access to all the info your friends did. Huge privacy violation, and many companies used this to their advantage (you could "friend" a potential employee and suddenly see all their facebook posts).

On Facebook the "Fan Page" makes a human clearly distinct from a product, service, interest or even celebrity's page. Arguably the difference is **people have a Profile describing them**, which is usually put together of canonical personal information.

Companies have a **Page constructed by them**, usually by a marketing team. They serve a similar function but the profile is assumed to be literally true and not "marketing". A company is assumed to have put together information supporting their business, not simply a description of what they are.